# Generate random string of numbers of random length

Tags: c++, string, random

I'm trying to automate test cases for my program and i wanted to generate random strings of numbers to test with... First test will be with base 2 numbers, so i want to generate 0's and 1's, of a random length n, where n is from 1 to 100. This is what i have so far, and it keeps returning the same string, (same length) and only generates either a 1, or a 0 for the entire length of the string.

```
int digNum = rand() % 100 + 1;
int num;

for(int i = 0; i < digNum; i++) {
    num = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) + 1;
    s1 = s1 + to_string(num);
}
cout << s1 << endl;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you initialized `srand`, i.e. called something like `srand (time(NULL))`?

Comment: Think a little while about what `(double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)` does. Then think about what happens when you convert that to an integer.

Comment: You should look at the [random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) standard library (available since c++11) - It is much more versatile than `rand()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the 0/1 problem :**

num = rand()%2;

Will generate a number that is 0 or 1 more simply.
With your current expression, rand()/RAND_MAX is always <1, unless rand()==RAND_MAX, in which case it equals 1 . Adding 1 gives almost always 1, or 2 if rand()==RND_MAX

**For the constant result**

Even if rand() returns a pseudo random sequence, it will always generate the same sequence at program start by default. The result will be different if you call it a second time in the same program, as you advanced in the random number sequence. If you want the first calls to rand() of each proces run tu return different results, you have to call

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

before calling rand()

Comment: All great answers, am grateful for all. This answer was well explained, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use `<random>` to generate your strings if you have C++11 or higher.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int genRandom(std::mt19937 & mt, int ls, int rs)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(ls, rs);
    return distribution(mt);
}

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 mt_rand;
    auto seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    mt_rand.seed(static_cast<unsigned>(seed));

    std::string randomString(genRandom(mt_rand, 0, 100), ' ');
    std::generate(std::begin(randomString), std::end(randomString), [&] () { return '0' + (genRandom(mt_rand, 0, 1)); });
    std::cout << randomString << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First you should initialize generator, e.g:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

With this you will make sure you won't get the same numbers every time.

And in order to generate numbers from range you should try:

```
rand() % (max + 1 - min) + min
```

Comment: Each time you call `rand()/RAND_MAX`, it will give you a number between 0 and 1. So all you need is to decide whether this number is greater than 0.5, then it is 1, if smaller then it is 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you divide srand() function by RAND_MAX you get a number in 0..1, and by casting to integer you get in lot of cases 0 (due to truncation). And finally 0 + 1 is 1.

Maybe you need something like this:
rand() % (base) i.e. `rand() % (2)`

Don't forget to initialize random number generator:
`srand(time(NULL));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) to generate integer values.

```
#include <random>
#include <string>

template <typename Generator>
std::string random_binary_string(Generator& g, std::size_t n) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<char> d('0', '1');

    std::string s;
    s.reserve(n);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        s += d(g);
    }

    return s;
}

template <typename Generator>
std::size_t random_size(Generator& g, std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> d(a, b);
    return d(g);
}
```

A [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) will usually generate non-deterministic random numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::random_device g;
    std::cout << random_binary_string(g, random_size(g, 1, 100)) << std::endl;
}
```